# Windows crash in ChangeServiceConfig2

Tags: windows, service, named-pipes

I'm having a problem with ChangeServiceConfig2(...SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO...)

Relevant code:

```
    WCHAR test[] = L"TEST12";
    SERVICE_TRIGGER_SPECIFIC_DATA_ITEM stdata {
        SERVICE_TRIGGER_DATA_TYPE_STRING,
        wcslen(test)*sizeof(WCHAR),
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(test)
    };
    SERVICE_TRIGGER st {
        SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_NETWORK_ENDPOINT,
        SERVICE_TRIGGER_ACTION_SERVICE_START,
        const_cast<GUID*>(&NAMED_PIPE_EVENT_GUID),
        1, &stdata
    };
    ChangeServiceConfig2(Service, SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO, &st);
```

This causes an Access Violation on address 00000009, so clearly an unchecked null pointer. And it's not a null pointer in `st` or `stdata`. The address 00000009 does not depend on the length of `test[]`.

> Stack dump:
>
> rpcrt4.dll!NdrpEmbeddedRepeatPointerBufferSize()
>     rpcrt4.dll!NdrConformantArrayBufferSize()
>     rpcrt4.dll!NdrSimpleStructBufferSize()
>     rpcrt4.dll!NdrpUnionBufferSize()
>     rpcrt4.dll!_NdrNonEncapsulatedUnionBufferSize@12()
>     rpcrt4.dll!NdrComplexStructBufferSize()
>     rpcrt4.dll!NdrClientCall2()     rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall4()
>     sechost.dll!ChangeServiceConfig2W()

The `Service` member is not the problem, or `ChangeServiceConfig2` itself: I can set the service description via `ChangeServiceConfig2(Service, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, &desc);`. The problem appears to be in the parsing of `SERVICE_TRIGGER`. Named Pipe service triggers apparently work for the Remote Registry service, so it's not fundamentally broken.

Q: which part of my `SERVICE_TRIGGER` is wrong?

<sub>Obviously there is at least one bug in Windows; at the very least it fails in parameter validation.</sub>

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091210-00/?p=15713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SERVICE_TRIGGER` object is correct, but `ChangeServiceConfig2` wants a `SERVICE_TRIGGER_INFO`. Simple solution: wrap `st` using `SERVICE_TRIGGER_INFO sti{ 1, &st, NULL };`